# How to convert array of arrays to array of objects where keys are taken from the first array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a variable that is returning an array of arrays, with each item in each array in double quotes.

```
var arrayOfArrays = [
  [ "Name", "Age", "Address" ],
  [ "A", "43", "CA" ],
  [ "B", "23", "VA" ],
  [ "C", "24", "NY" ]
]
```

I need to convert this to the following:

```
var arrayOfObjects = [
  {"Name":"A", "Age":"43", "Address":"CA"},
  {"Name":"B", "Age":"23", "Address":"VA"},
  {"Name":"C", "Age":"24", "Address":"NY"}
]
```

Comment: Not AngularJS related, removed tags

Comment: Hi I have a little tricky situation but little bit similiar to it
[ [ { name: 'item_label_id',
      value: '000431a0-cf95-4ac9-af52-2a66f929a25f' } ],
  [ { name: 'item_label_id',
      value: '000563b6-de35-40e6-9c27-faa4416cd67b' } ]]
I want this Array of Arrays like this
{"name":"item_label_id","value":"'000431a0-cf95-4ac9-af52-2a66f929a25f'","Name":"xyz","Value":"234"}
Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Update

Less verbose version using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with newer language constructs like [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```js
const arrays = [
  ["Name", "Age", "Address"],
  ["A", "43", "CA"],
  ["B", "23", "VA"],
  ["C", "24", "NY"]
];

const [keys, ...values] = arrays;
const objects = values.map(array => array.reduce((a, v, i) => ({...a, [keys[i]]: v}), {}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(objects));
```

---

#### Original answer

Using [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const arrays = [
  ["Name", "Age", "Address"],
  ["A", "43", "CA"],
  ["B", "23", "VA"],
  ["C", "24", "NY"]
];

const keys = arrays[0];
const values = arrays.slice(1);
const objects = values.map(array => {
  const object = {};

  keys.forEach((key, i) => object[key] = array[i]);
  
  return object;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(objects));
```

Comment: Hello Robby, Thanks for your quick response. I am not using Angular2, could you please post the answer in angular js?

Comment: This is pure JavaScript and has nothing to do with AngularJS or Angular 2. Btw, you yourself added the `angular2` tag to your question.

Comment: Thank you, Robby! Do you have any idea of doing this in Angular ?

Comment: Do you have any idea of doing this in Angular ?

Comment: What's the difference? JavaScript is JavaScript, no?

Comment: I def like this, I had to use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objects))` to get the result I wanted.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps

```
var arrayOfArrays = [
      [ "Name", "Age", "Address" ],
      [ "A", "43", "CA" ],
      [ "B", "23", "VA" ],
      [ "C", "24", "NY" ]
    ]
var arrayOfObjects = [];

function changeToObject(arrayOfArrays){  
    for (var i = 1; i < arrayOfArrays.length; i++) {
        var json = {
            "Name" : "",
            "Age" : "",
            "Address" : ""
        }
        json.Name = arrayOfArrays[i][0];
        json.Age = arrayOfArrays[i][1];
        json.Address = arrayOfArrays[i][2];
        arrayOfObjects.push(json);  
    };
    console.log(arrayOfObjects)

}

changeToObject(arrayOfArrays);
```